# No Solr in Sitecore 10 CD

Tags: solr

I would like to know if Solr is needed in CD environment? We don't use Solr as our site search but a different search provider.

Thanks

Comment: You can disable Solr if your CD instance is not using features like Buckets, any code that depends on indexes for rendering components

Comment: What other Search provider are you using? I imagine it is Azure Search if you are on Sitecore 10. Any xDB functionality will be interrupted here if you completely break off from any Search engine. if you are removing Solr indexes, see if you can point it to Azure Search.

Answer (score 1):

It is safe to remove it on the CD instance however you need to check all your configurations to verify it is not used anywhere, especially your custom index definitions and the sitecore indexes, for example the xDB search index https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/100/sitecore-experience-platform/en/the-xdb-search-index.html. Another area you would need to look into is if you are using any sitecore modules that are using search queries.

Answer (score 0):

We have a project where we have disabled Solr on a CD server. Basically you can do that. But take into account that Sitecore Buckets use search and it will not work on CD server with Solr disabled. Also make sure that you don't use it somewhere in item resolving process and so on.